# Faster RCNN indefinitely Trainer

Tags: tensorflow, faster-rcnn

i have a config file For 
faster_rcnn_resnet50_coco.config

and there is some line like

eval_config: {
  num_examples: 8000
  # Note: The below line limits the evaluation process to 10 evaluations.
  # Remove the below line to evaluate indefinitely.
  max_evals: 10
}

**what actually happened if i remove max_evals

## Remove the below line to evaluate indefinitely.

what actually mean by indefinitely**

also for number of steps

# never decay). Remove the below line to train indefinitely.
  num_steps: 200000
when should trainer stop if i remove num of steps line and what again mean by indefinitely

thanks and best regards